# Pthreads in Codelite 6.1 on ubuntu 14.04.1 x64

Tags: c, ubuntu, pthreads, codelite

I trying to compile a simple C program with Pthreads in Ubuntu with codelite.

I have chosen GCC as my compiler and have added the "-pthread" into the C compiler options in the project settings. But it throws an error `"undefined reference to pthread_create"` on compile time.

If I call GCC via command line manually it builds and runs.

But when I comment out the offending line it compiles with no errors in codelite.

So I suspect that codelite is not adding the -pthread compiler flag when compiling.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>


//function prototypes
void * monitor_thread (void* data);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// exit program if no arguments are supplied
if(argc < 3)
{
    printf("Not enough arguments passed \n");
    return 0;
}

// parse arguments
int arrivalProbability = atoi(argv[1]);
int departureProbability = atoi(argv[2]);

// exit the program in entered values are not valid
if (arrivalProbability >=90 || departureProbability >=90)
{
    printf("Argument(s) exceed a probability of 90%% \n");
    return 0;
}   
else if (arrivalProbability == 0 || departureProbability == 0)
{
    printf("Argument(s)entered are zero or not intergers \n");
    return 0;
}

// create the threads
int        thr_id;              /* thread ID for the newly created thread */
pthread_t  p_thread;            /* thread's structure                     */
int        monitor      = 1;    /* monitor thread identifying number      */
int        arrival      = 2;    /* arrival thread identifying number      */
int        departure    = 3;    /* departure thread identifying number    */



// monitor thead
// "undefined reference to pthread_create"
thr_id = pthread_create(&p_thread, NULL, monitor_thread, (void*)&monitor);

return 0;
}

void * monitor_thread (void* data)
{
int monitorThreadID = *((int*)data);     /* thread identifying number */
printf("monitor thread");
sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: undefined reference is linker error. That indicates -pthread is missing from linker parameters.

Comment: Have you tried -lpthread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right on the project icon on the left tree view and select settings -> common settings -> linker -> linker options

And add there `-pthreads`
Btw, pasting the build log could have help other people to help you faster.

Eran

Comment: The build log only showed the "undefined reference to pthread_create". Putting '-pthread' into both the compiler and linker options did the trick.

Comment: it is without "s" at the end!